# Accumulating numbers in an array without a loop. (python)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

So I have a (seemingly) simple problem, which I am currently doing now via a for loop.

Basically, I want to increment specific cells in a numpy matrix, but I want to do it without a for-loop if possible.

To give more details: I have `100 x 100` numpy matrix, `X`. I also have a `2x1000` numpy matrix `P`. `P` just stores indices into `X`, so for example, each column of `P`, has the row-column index of the cell, that I want to increment in `X`.

What I do right now is this:

```
for p in range(P.shape[1]):
  X[P[0,p], P[1,p]] += 1
```

My question is, is there a way to do this without a for-loop?

Thanks!

Comment: `for p in range(P.shape[1]):` probably?

Comment: @Divakar yes sorry, corrected the typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method of the `add` ufunc with [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
numpy.add.at(X, (P[0], P[1]), 1)
```

or just advanced indexing if `P` is guaranteed to never select the same cell of `X` twice:

```
X[P[0], P[1]] += 1
```

Comment: `P[0], P[1]` can be expressed more generally as `(*P,)`. So `numpy.add.at(X, (*P,), 1)` and `X[(P,)] += 1`. This is nice because it does not hard code in the number of dimensions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Or just `tuple(P)`, but I picked `P[0], P[1]` because it felt clearer to me for this case.

Comment: Hi, it is very possible to have repeated indices. Does this mean that I should use the first option? Second question is, why is the first option better than a for loop? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond. Python `for` loops are not great for speed. Functionally, the loop is no different than using `add.at`, but it will be much slower and require more text to type.

Comment: Yeah, but why is it faster anyway? Like, what is happening under the hood that makes it faster? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: C-level loop directly over the array's backing store, instead of a Python-level loop that would have to go through the bytecode evaluation loop and dispatch everything dynamically and construct wrapper objects and all that JITless dynamic language overhead.

Comment: Thanks user! Last question, would a python wrapper that wrapped a C-level code work similarly? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond: That's what this is, so assuming you write a similar wrapper and similar C-level code, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Using `linear-indices` and `bincount` -

```
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(P, X.shape)
X += np.bincount(lidx, minlength=X.size).reshape(X.shape)
```

### Benchmarking

For the case when indices are not repeated, `advanced indexing` based approach as suggested in [`@user2357112's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46203177/) seems to be very efficient.

For repeated ones case, we have `np.add.at` and `np.bincount` and the performance numbers seem to be dependent on the size of indices array relative to the size of input array.

Approaches -

```
 def app0(X,P): # @user2357112's soln1
     np.add.at(X, (P[0], P[1]), 1)

 def app1(X, P): # Proposed in this ppst
     lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(P, X.shape)
     X += np.bincount(lidx, minlength=X.size).reshape(X.shape)
```

Here's few timing tests to suggest that -

Case #1 :

```
 In [141]: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(100,100))
      ...: P = np.random.randint(0,100,(2,1000))
      ...: 

 In [142]: %timeit app0(X, P)
      ...: %timeit app1(X, P)
      ...: 
 10000 loops, best of 3: 68.9 µs per loop
 100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop
```

Case #2 :

```
 In [143]: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,1000))
      ...: P = np.random.randint(0,1000,(2,10000))
      ...: 

 In [144]: %timeit app0(X, P)
      ...: %timeit app1(X, P)
      ...: 
 1000 loops, best of 3: 687 µs per loop
 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop
```

Case #3 :

```
 In [145]: X = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000,1000))
      ...: P = np.random.randint(0,1000,(2,100000))
      ...: 

 In [146]: %timeit app0(X, P)
      ...: %timeit app1(X, P)
      ...: 
 100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
 100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop
```

Comment: Took me a while to realize why you were doing that. Repeated indices are a pain.